# Looking for graphic novel series with a bunch of quiche pies

Tags: story-identification, books, graphic-novel

I read this series around four to five years ago. The publishing date was a few years before that.

What I remember:

- The main character is drawn kind of like Snoopy, but without the ears
- The main character might have been named Skull [unsure]
- MC falls in love with a girl (drawn human)
- **They make a ton of quiche pies**
- There are these weird hairy monkey-like characters with sharp claws and teeth who follow a hooded character (the villain of the story)
- Series with over 6 books
- The girl is the granddaughter of the nemesis of the hooded character

Comment: Has anybody seen… a dog dyed dark green?

Comment: @Lexible I don't think I put that in my question?

Comment: It is a reference to a song titled "Quiche Lorraine".

Comment: @Lexible Ohhhhh, I see. Ty for the clarification :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your description of the characters makes me think of Jeff Smith's [*Bone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone_(comics)); the main character Fone Bone is all white with a round head and a bulbous nose.  He falls in love with Thorn Harvester when her first meets her; she is drawn like a normal young woman with blue eyes and light hair.  The hooded villain is, appropriately enough, the Hooded One and the creatures are Rat Creatures.

Bone:

[image: Bone, wearing a backpack, looking at a map]

I'll see if I can dig up any good (fair-use appropriate) images for the others.

Comment: But do they make quiche? That, I think, is the important question.

Comment: There does seem to be a running joke of the Rat Creatures craving quiche, e.g. https://i.pinimg.com/236x/aa/73/bf/aa73bf213e299beb2664e9c6129ded81--jeff-smith-quiche.jpg and https://www.boneville.com/wp-content/uploads/10_22_20.jpg

Comment: Ah, and apparently it is just one. At one point, Fone Bone makes said Rat Creature a quiche as a thank you gift, but I'm not finding a panel with a bunch of quiche.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Thanks for checking; TBF I'm more aware of *Bone* than actually _familiar_ with it.  Like I said the characters are a really good match for the question; I assumed the quiche stuff would have been in one I didn't read.

Comment: As soon as I read "quiche" my mind went straight to Bone! There's a long running joke about how one of the rat Creatures keeps wanting to make quiches and the other is embarrassed, feeling they aren't proper food for a monster. I can't remember seeing a bunch of them, but since it's a recurring joke the OP may have confabulated it.

Comment: @terdon I remember a bunch of quiche, just not what scenes. So I put emphasis.